# journalctl process eating up memory

Tags: centos, systemd

I have a process run by root `journalctl -b --system` showing up on htop that is eating a ton of CPU. I understand journalctl is for querying the journal, so is it safe to kill the job without impact on the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`journalctl` is an interactive console command for querying the journal. The options `-b`and `--system` are merely used to restrict the generated listing to specific criteria. Since neither the command nor its options involve any modifications to the journal database, in my opinion it's safe to kill the job.